# How do I make a bookmark / favorite / weblink that opens a webpage in a small window?

Tags: javascript

How do I make a bookmark / favorite / weblink or command line command, that opens a webpage in a small window?

For example, [this page for BBC Radio 6](http://www.bbc.co.uk/6music/) has a link for [Listen Live](http://www.bbc.co.uk/iplayer/console/bbc_6music), which opens the player in a small window.  But when I bookmark that window and use it, I get a full sized window.

I guess it is done with JavaScript.  But how do I find the JavaScript used, and how do I apply it to a bookmark file (or command line)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a browser issue at its core.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct you do this using JavaScript.

Create a new bookmark and instead of putting the web address in you would use this:

```
javascript:function LoadPlayer() { return window.open("http://www.bbc.co.uk/iplayer/console/bbc_6music","BBC 6 Music","scrollbars=no,menubar=no,height=721,width=400,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no");} LoadPlayer();
```

When you click the bookmark it will open in a new window.

The JavaScript used to do this is called [window.open](http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml)

Comment: Thanks.  I've tried this (on Windows), but when I click on the .url file I get IE9's download manager come up instead, even when Firefox is the default browser.  Which setup are you using?

Comment: @paradroid - I am using Google Chrome on Windows 7

Comment: But without IE9 Beta installed?  It looks like this JS bookmark does not work with IE9, as it brings up its download manager for some reason.